# <include/> tags in arrays.xml

Tags: android, xml, arrays, resources

I have seen how to include some layouts in other layout xml files, and I was wondering if the same would somehow be manageable inside the 'arrays.xml' file. Any succeeding out there ? An example please ?

Thank you!

Comment: I have never seen this kind of thing and dont think if its possible. May be what you want is array within array ...??

Comment: AFAIK, `<include>` only works with layout files.